# MongoDB: how to retrieve part of an embedded document?

Tags: mongodb

I have this Datasets collection populate like this:

```
* A Datasets's element *
{
    _id: xQ2kqEdoewjPxpKQ5,
    name: "dataset_name",
    data : [
        {x: 0, y: -375.800005599856},
        {x: 0.000666666659526527, y: -375.300005592406},
        {x: 0.00133333331905305, y: -375.200005590916},
        {x: 0.00199999997857958, y: -375.400005593896},
        {x: 0.00266666663810611, y: -375.200005590916},
        {x: 0.00333333329763263, y: -374.700005583465},
        {x: 0.00399999995715916, y: -374.100005574524},
        {x: 0.00466666661668569, y: -373.800005570054},
        {x: 0.00533333327621222, y: -374.400005578995},
        {x: 0.00599999993573874, y: -375.300005592406},
        {x: 0.00666666659526527, y: -375.800005599856},
        {x: 0.0073333332547918, y: -376.300005607307},
        {x: 0.00799999991431832, y: -376.800005614758},
        {x: 0.00866666657384485, y: -377.400005623698},
        {x: 0.00933333323337138, y: -377.700005628169},
        {x: 0.0099999998928979, y: -378.000005632639}
    ]
}
```

To plot, I need to retrive only points {x,y} where x is between, let's say xMin (0.005) and xMax (0.007).

So I want to be returned:

```
{
    {x: 0.00533333327621222, y: -374.400005578995},
    {x: 0.00599999993573874, y: -375.300005592406},
    {x: 0.00666666659526527, y: -375.800005599856}
}
```

How can I do that?
I am currently looking in the aggregate direction. Is that good?

Comment: I think `data` should be an array . given document structure not a valid json.

Comment: Have a look on this: `$gt`, `$lt`, `$elemMatch` might help you.

Comment: @GauravDave So you think that I should try a .findOne()?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your query should look like this:

```
    db.collection.aggregate([ 
       { $match: {_id: "xQ2kqEdoewjPxpKQ5"} }, 
       { $unwind: "$data" }, 
       { $match: { "data.x": { $gt:xMin, $lt : xMax } },
       { $project : { _id: 0, data : 1 } }
       { $sort: { "data.x": 1 } }, 
       { $limit: 3 } 
   ])
```

Your result should look like this:

```
    { "data" : { x: 0.00533333327621222, y: -374.400005578995} }
    { "data" : { x: 0.00599999993573874, y: -375.300005592406} }
    { "data" : { x: 0.00666666659526527, y: -375.800005599856} }
```

Comment: Oh thanks. That was that I tried to design. Now I need to join them, but I don't think it will be a problem. I am testing, and then I'll come back here. Thanks Anton!

Comment: Thanks Anton. I succeeded to get my array of coordinates  by passing the aggregate result into the followinf flattenData function:
`function flattenData(array){
    var flattenedData = [];
    for(i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
        flattenedData = flattenedData.concat(_.flatten(array[i], true));
    }
    return flattenedData;
}`